# Proving that a SCII character is really owned by the one who claims to be the owner

Tags: starcraft-2

*This question is related to my [same question for WoW](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/proving-that-a-wow-character-is-really-owned-by-the-one-who-claims-to-be-the-owne). I promise that it's the last. I have all the answers for other games. WoW and SCII was the only 2 missing.*

Is there a way to prove by any way that a special character is really owned by a player.

I explain myself:

On a website, users can add their SC2 account to show their statistics on the website.

How to ensure that the user on the website really owns the account (and is not "stealing" statistics from a really good known other player) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with close votes on this one.  While his particular use case may be off topic, the question of: "how do I prove someone is who they say they are in SCII?" is a valid question for people in a competitive online game

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some sites when you register an B.net account ask you to change the portrait to one of the available portraits form the accounts rewards section.

As the account picture can only be changed in game, the user logs in to their SC2 account changes the picture. Once changed they tell the site to scan the picture again, if it matches the account is confirmed.

This is how sc2replayed.com and wellplayed.org have confirmed my account with their sites.